# Prevent Users From changing their own permission

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a middleware for admins

And I applied it in my routes.

So the problem when the user is admin he can go to users page and change his permissions and the page keeps redirecting and breaks when he clicks change permission to his profile :

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

my method to change user to admin :

```
public function admin($id){


        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->admin = 1;

        $user->save();

        session()->flash('success','Changed to admin');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

And to change user to Author :

```
  public function notAdmin($id){


            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            $user->admin = 0;

            $user->save();

            session()->flash('success','Changed to Normal');



            return redirect()->back();




    }
```

So how I can prevent the logged in user from changing his permissions?

I'm really confused about this.
Thank you

Comment: use sessions to limit their access on certain pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the user if he tries to change his own permissions by using
Auth->id() and comparing with $id so that if these things match then he is trying to change his own permission.
    public function admin($id){

```
    if(Auth->id() == $id) {
      session()->flash('error','Permission denied');
      return redirect()->back();        
    }

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $user->admin = 1;

    $user->save();

    session()->flash('success','Changed to admin');

    return redirect()->back();

}
```